# How to automatically update android:versionName?

Tags: android, svn, manifest

For an improved bugreporting I'd like if the tag `android:versionName` automatically contains the number of the revision on the svn server. Anyone knows how to do that? Thanks

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`svn:keywords`](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/10923_3503151_4/A-Crash-Course-in-Subversion-Part-2.htm).

Comment: I read it, but the text says that the following keywords are supported: "HeadURL (abbreviated as URL), which expands to the URL of the file in the repository; LastChangedBy (abbreviated as Author), which expands to the username of the last person who modified the file; LastChangedDate (abbreviated as Date), which stores the date on which the file was last modified; LastChangedRevision (abbreviated as Rev), which stores the revision in which the file last changed; and Id, which stores a compressed version of the other four keywords." So if I understand it correctly I have to use this identifier

Comment: in the manifest file to replace the android:versionName but then it only works if the manifest is also changed if I commit a new revision?

Comment: I have not used SVN in quite some time. Back when I did use it, `svn:keywords` expanded on checkout. So, your process to go to production needs to do a build from a fresh checkout, and then the manifest file will contain the `Rev` keyword wherever you place it.

Comment: the problem is, i can't save something like this in the manifest:
android:versionName=$Rev$

Comment: svn:keywords "LastChangedRevision" is _not_ what you want; that gives you the last revision in which this particular file was modified.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [start-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks) that writes the current time stamp into the android:versionName in the manifest. You'd have to write a small script that uses some regex to insert the current time stamp into the AndroidManifest.xml, and then call that as pre-commit hook

The revision number that's being checked in is not yet known for the start-commit hook, so you cannot write it to the manifest.

I haven't really used those hooks myself. As far as I understand, you can make a directory /repoName/.svn/hook/, and inside that, you create one or more executables, e.g. "start-commit", that does what you want.

This seems like a nice starting point if you want to know more about the hooks: [A Subversion Pre-Commit Hook](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook)